# Keyboardinterrupt doesn't stop threading to keep on going in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, exception, keyboardinterrupt

This code is running fine, my only problem is when I need to stop my code, I enter ctrl+c despite giving :

```
for thread in threads:
    thread.alive = False
    thread.join()
    sys.exit(e)
```

In the code, the thread keeps on running, say the thread has to download, even after keyinterrupt it keeps on download. What can I do to exit the code gracefully?

This the complete code :

```
 try:
    threads = []
    while len(list1) != 0:
        while len(threads) != 4:
            time.sleep(1)
            item = list1.pop(0)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(item, ))
            threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
        for thread in threads:
            if not thread.is_alive():
                # get results from thread
                threads.remove(thread)
        if len(list1) == 0:
            logging.error("Nothing")
            sys.exit(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    logging.error("Keyboard Interruption, code exiting!!")
    list1.append(item)
    logging.info(f'{item} Adding back to the list')
    # whenever there is a keyboard interrupt kill all the threads
    for thread in threads:
        thread.alive = False
        thread.join()
        sys.exit(e)
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(f'Failed to initiate the threads : {e}')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `thread.alive = False` won't do anything unless the thread actually cares about the flag. If you want to terminate gracefully, you need to modify your target `func` to periodically check the value of `alive` and stop running if it's `False`.

Alternatively, if you don't care about graceful shutdowns and just want all threads to exit when the main thread does, you can add [`daemon=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) to the Thread constructor when you create them.

Comment: yes gracefully is what I am looking for, daemon can or may abrupt my data. but m weighing this as well

Comment: @DarcyM Post the code for your target `func` -- it'll need to check the `alive` value and clean up when it becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need is to find a way to kill a thread. This is not usually advisable, especially when the thread is reading/writing to a file for example, or when the thread is handling other threads. I'd recommend reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread) for more details.

You could create a custom thread wrapper to handle stopping threads safely, or if you use the `multiprocessing` library, you can call `process.terminate()`.

Comment: I am not able to open the link you provided above

Comment: That's strange, it doesn't work any more. I'll try and fix it.

Comment: @DarcyM Problem fixed.